# firefox creating an extra a tag in html

Tags: html

Sorry for the little information on the title, Here's my html:

```
<body>
<header class="header">
    <nav class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo">
            <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="header__menu">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>

        <div class="header__links">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#"><a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Careers</a>
        </div>

        <a class='btn' href="#">Button</button>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>
```

but firefox is creating an extra a tag outside the header inside the body, same as the last one:
`<a class='btn' href="#">Button</button>`.

chromium is also acting same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [HTML Validation service](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea), you will find bunch of problems, among others:

```
Unclosed element a.
From line 22, column 9; to line 22, column 32

↩↩        <a class='btn' href="#">Button
```

Here you opened `<a>` tag, but incorrectly closed it with `</button>`

```
<a class='btn' href="#">Button</button>
```

so browser will do best effort to figure out correct DOM

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are opening and closing the right tags.
It is not making an extra tag, it is closing the tag since you are closing an undefined button, not the actual anchor tag.

You can fix this by replacing `<a class='btn' href="#">Button</button>` with `<a class='btn' href="#">Button</a>`.

It is not a browser issue, it is a code issue.